# What is the type of plot called?

Tags: data-visualization

I ran into this image and find it very intuitive. However, I have never seen anything similar.

I would be interested to make similar ones myself, and if anyone knows any programming package that is able to produce this graph, it would be great.

[image]

Comment: https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/liverpool-can-end-english-soccers-cycle-of-embarrassment/ (for reference).

Comment: I don't know of a name for this particular plot type (I doubt it has one).  Given data you could do it in any sufficient flexible plotting system (e.g. R base graphics or ggplot2), but I doubt it's going to be feasible "out of the box", i.e. without you or someone else doing some custom programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the individual plots appears to be a [barplot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_chart) where the bars are shown going vertically downward, the teams are grouped into leagues by colour on the horizontal axis, and the vertical axis is a measure of the number of competition stages through which the team successfully progressed.  The overall chart is a facet-wrap of multiple barplots, with each one being for a different year.

It should be possible to program a chart like this using `ggplot2` in `R` but it would require customisation of an appropriate data frame and a complicated expression for the plot.  I would suggest starting by seeing if you can replicate a single barplot with the teams grouped into leagues by colour using `geom_bar` and using dummy data with values of zero for the spaces between the leagues.  You could then flip the bars to go downward and customise the axis label to the desired labels.  Once you can reproduce a single plot it should be trivial to use `facet_wrap` to show one for each year.

Comment: This is very inspiring, thanks a lot. Now that you mentioned barplot, I think it would be possible to reproduce this graph by doing a horizontal bar, grouped by the leagues, and ranked vertically based on the stage of the tournament.

Comment: I think there may be subtle but important differences between this chart and your description.  It's not faceted because the order of leagues varies from one year to the next and so do the orders of contenders with each league.  Although the geometries can be created as unions of bars, conceptually these aren't quite barplots, either: they are somewhat complex representations of the successes of representatives of each league--whose individuals and counts can (and do) vary over time.